# ionic correct way to setup a two part tab

Tags: ionic-framework

I have a `tabs.html` setup with four page-tabs in it. One of these pages contains six items and upon selecting an item I want a new page to slide into view but it won't be one of the other tab items.

Is it better have the new page as a hidden tab or to have it be a page outside of the tabs? I need to pass the existing page's `$scope` data to transfer to new page (for data of the item tapped on) and I need the new page to animate the new page in.

Comment: Do you mean this other page should not have the tabs? If I understand you mean you really want two pages, a page with the tabs (and perhaps those are subpages) and another page.

Comment: @JeremyWilken Yes you said it best, I want a "sub page" of one of the tabs. I don't mind the parent tab's button keeping the active look but I don't think it works that way. If it doesn't then I'm going to just add a back button to the new subpage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the other page to be outside of the tabs. If you try to make a 'fake' tab, I can only imagine that will be the source of much pain and many bugs. It is best to use things as intended instead of hacking on top of them. You may want to consider a side menu to expose navigation that doesn't fit into normal tabs interactions.

See my codepen here for one quickly hacked together example. http://codepen.io/gnomeontherun/pen/OVLQYL?editors=101

```js
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
      url: '/',
      controller: 'HomeCtrl',
      templateUrl: 'home.html'
    })
    .state('item', {
      url: '/:item',
      controller: 'ItemCtrl',
      templateUrl: 'item.html'
    });

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
})
.controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope, $ionicSideMenuDelegate, $ionicModal) {
  $scope.stooges = [{name: 'Moe'}, {name: 'Larry'}, {name: 'Curly'}];

  $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('modal.html', {
    animation: 'slide-in-up',
    scope: $scope
  }).then(function (modal) {
    $scope.modal = modal;
  });
  
  $scope.openMenu = function () {
    $ionicSideMenuDelegate.toggleLeft();
  }
  
  $scope.openModal = function () {
    $scope.modal.show();
  }
  
  $scope.form = {};
  
  $scope.addStooge = function () {
    console.log($scope);
    $scope.stooges.push({name: $scope.form.name});
    $scope.modal.hide();
  };
  
  $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
     $scope.modal.remove();
  });

})
.controller('ItemCtrl', function ($scope, $stateParams) {
  $scope.item = $stateParams.item;
});
```

```html
<html ng-app="ionicApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width"> 
    
    <title>Ionic Modal</title>

    <link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-rc.3/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-rc.3/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    
     <ion-side-menus>
      <ion-side-menu-content>
        <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive nav-title-slide-ios7">
          <ion-nav-back-button class="button-icon"><span class="icon ion-ios-arrow-left"></span></ion-nav-back-button>
        </ion-nav-bar>
        <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
      </ion-side-menu-content>

      <ion-side-menu side="left">
        <ion-header-bar class="bar bar-header bar-dark"></ion-header-bar>
        <ion-content>
          <ion-list>
            <ion-item href="#/" menu-toggle="left">Home</ion-item>
          </ion-list>
        </ion-content>
      </ion-side-menu>

      <ion-side-menu side="right" >
        <ion-header-bar class="bar-header bar-dark">
          <h1 class="title">Search</h1>
        </ion-header-bar>
        <ion-content>

        </ion-content>
      </ion-side-menu>
    </ion-side-menus>
    
    <script id="home.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-view title="Home">
        <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
          <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-plus" ng-click="openModal()"></button>
        </ion-nav-buttons>
        <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
          <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left"></button>
        </ion-nav-buttons>        
          <ion-tabs class="tabs-positive">
            <ion-tab title="Stooges">
              <ion-content class="has-header">
              <h4>The Stooges</h4>
          <ion-list>
            <ion-item ng-repeat="stooge in stooges" href="#/{{stooge.name}}">{{stooge.name}}</ion-item>
          </ion-list>
                </ion-content>
              </ion-tab>
            <ion-tab title="Tab 2">
              <ion-content class="has-header">
              <h2>Just another tab, for another reason</h2>
                </ion-content>
              </ion-tab>
            </ion-tabs>
      </ion-view>
    </script>
    
    <script id="modal.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <div class="modal">
        <ion-header-bar class="bar-header bar-positive">
          <h1 class="title">New Stooge</h1>
          <button class="button button-clear button-primary" ng-click="modal.hide()">Cancel</button>
        </ion-header-bar>
        <ion-content>
          <div class="padding">
            <div class="list">
              <label class="item item-input">
                <span class="input-label">Name</span>
                <input ng-model="form.name" type="text" name="name" />
              </label>
              <button class="button button-full button-positive" ng-click="addStooge()">Create</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </ion-content>
      </div>
    </script>
    
    <script id="item.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-view title="{{item}}">
        <ion-content>
          <h1>{{item}}</h1>
        </ion-content>
      </ion-view>
    </script>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Question, on your `.state` for "item" you set the `url` as "/:item" - What's the significance of the colon? I'm almost confused on how "#/Moe" knows how to pull up the "item.html" template.

Comment: `:item` designates that as a `$stateParam` so `/moe` would set `$stateParams.item = moe` so you could grab that in the controller.